# Problem when trying to create a left-aligned text using kivy

Tags: python, kivy, alignment

I'm fairly new to Kivy, I've made a few small apps and stuff like that, but now I'm having a problem trying to create left-aligned typing effect text.

My idea was to have the text appear on the corner of the screen, similar to a terminal (I'll leave an example image taken from **Pydroid**). I was able to achieve this with static text, but for my project, I also needed a typing effect, which I also managed to implement. However, when trying to combine the two, I couldn't get the text to align to the left. It always stays in the middle.

My code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_to_type= self.text

        self.text = ""
 
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.type_text, 0.05)

    def type_text(self, txt):
        if len(self.text) < len(self.text_to_type):
            self.text += self.text_to_type[len(self.text)]



class Example(App):
    def build(self):             
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        self.root.add_widget(MyLabel(text='''
That's a typing text!


And I'm trying to make it aligned!''',
        size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),
        halign="left",
        valign="bottom"))

        return self.root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().run()
```

How could I make it align to the left, looking like the example photo I posted?
Thanks in advance!

[Pydroid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EosJZ.jpg)
[What am I getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmbAP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `text_size` property of the `Label` in order for the alignment to work (see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign)). Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_to_type = self.text

        self.text = ""

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.type_text, 0.05)

    def type_text(self, txt):
        if len(self.text) < len(self.text_to_type):
            self.text += self.text_to_type[len(self.text)]

kv = '''
<MyLabel>:
     size_hint: (1.0, 1.0)
     text_size: self.size
     halign: "left"
     valign: "bottom"
'''


class Example(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        self.root.add_widget(MyLabel(text='''
That's a typing text!


And I'm trying to make it aligned!'''))

        return self.root


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().run()
```

Comment: It really worked. I had already read the documentation on this several times and I think I always missed this part about text_size, my mistake. 
I will pay more attention to it next time. Thank you very much, my friend.